# Partial não renderiza

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estou com um problema em minha aplicação. O que acontece é que eu não estou conseguindo renderizar um partial em um outra view.

Aqui o código do partial:

```
@model CEF01.Models.Ocorrencia

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Ocorrencia"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AlunoId)

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Ocorrencia</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tipo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tipo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tipo)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Causa, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Causa)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Causa)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Observacao, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Observacao)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Observacao)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

E aqui a parte em que eu tento renderizar esse partial em outra view:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#ocorrencias">
                Ocorrências do Aluno
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <div id="ocorrencias" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            @foreach (var ocorrencia in Model.Ocorrencias)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_AdicionaOcorrencia")
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Diretórios e seus respectivos arquivos:
Alunos:

- _AdicionaOcorrencia.cshtml
- Adiciona.cshtml
- Detalhes.cshtml
- Edita.cshtml
- Index.cshtml
- Remove.cshtml

Ocorrencias:
 - Adiciona.cshtml
 - Detalhes.cshtml
 - Edita.cshtml
 - Index.cshtml
 - Remove.cshtml

Shared:

Dentro de Shared tenho o diretório EditorTemplates e nele contém:

- Collection.cshtml

Dentro de Shared:

- _Layout.cshtml
- _LoginPartial.cshtml
- Error.cshtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você esqueceu de passar o Model para dentro da Partial. Veja a linha `@Html.Partial` abaixo:

```
<div id="ocorrencias" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
        @foreach (var ocorrencia in Model.Ocorrencias)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_AdicionaOcorrencia", ocorrencia)
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Outra coisa é se `Model.Ocorrencias` estiver vazio. Aí não vai aparecer mesmo. O que você pode fazer é:

```
<div id="ocorrencias" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
        @if (Model.Ocorrencias.Count > 0) {
            foreach (var ocorrencia in Model.Ocorrencias)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_AdicionaOcorrencia", ocorrencia)
            }
        } else {
            <div>Ainda não há ocorrências</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```